# Datetime format issue: how to convert datetime with 4 digit days or months

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, datetime

I'm trying to parse DateTime data from podcast XML.

Basically, it comprises http header format.

```
(Format-A) Fri, 28 Aug 2015 00:00:00 EST
```

But, sometimes it has the different format with 4 digit days and month like below.

```
(Format-B) Thur, 30 July 2015 00:00:00 EST
```

I don't know why the Podcast provides 2 different formats at the same time.

I thought I could simply parse this format as this website mentioned.

https://www.dotnetperls.com/datetime-parse

But it didn't work with just DateTime.Parse() method

So I wrote this code.

```
try
{
    dtPubDate = DateTime.ParseExact(strhttpTime,
    "ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss 'EST'",
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat,
    DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal);
}
catch (FormatException)
{
     dtPubDate = DateTime.ParseExact(strhttpTime,
     "dddd, dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss 'EST'",
     CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat,
     DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal);
}
```

As I wrote this code, if the first format doesn't work, try the second one.

But it still got the exception with Format-B.
This URL is what am having the problem with.
 http://www.thebreathingmusic.com/podcast/podcast.xml

As you can see, there are 2 different formats with pubDate tag.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format string `dddd` will match against the entire day name, e.g. "Thursday", not 4 characters.

From [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx#ddddSpecifier):

> The "dddd" custom format specifier (plus any number of additional "d" specifiers) represents the **full name of the day of the week**. The localized name of the day of the week is retrieved from the DateTimeFormatInfo.DayNames property of the current or specified culture.

You could just trim everything before the comma and parse that instead.

```
var tidyDate = strhttpTime.Split(',')[1].Trim();

dtPubDate = DateTime.ParseExact(
    tidyDate,
    "ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss 'EST'",
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat,
    DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal);
```